# How to download images asynchronously from web server

Tags: java, design-patterns, blackberry, threadpool, observer-pattern

My application screen looks similar to the image attached. I have multiple rows and each row has a Bitmap image, title and description field. All the information's are getting fetched from our supporting web-server in the form of XML. Now, I have used observer design pattern, which creates a separate thread for connecting to my remote server over HTTP, downloads and parse the XML. The XML includes the URL for image, title and description for  each row.

[image]

I have tried few approaches so far,

**Approach 1:**

- Created a separate method (drawRow()), which takes care of putting the contents together by specifying the layout.
- And, then using the method downloadImage(), I am trying to download the remote URL from the drawRow() method. **But it sucks, as it downloads using the same thread and UI gets blocked.**

**Approach 2:**

While searching for the above issue, I came across [WebBitmapField](http://www.coderholic.com/blackberry-webbitmapfield/) in blackberry from [coderholic.com](http://coderholic.com).

And, then I am using the below code from my drawRow() method. As I understand the WebBitmapField, here is using observer design pattern and the image is downloading over thread other than UI thread. It works fine when I have limited number of rows like 5 or 10. But when I have more number of rows to be drawn it throws `TooManyThreads` exception, as it creates a new thread for each row.

I have got this link [taskworker-thread-blackberry](http://blog.vimviv.com/j2me/taskworker-thread-blackberry/), but not much clear with how to achieve my requirement.

As I understand, in blackberry an application can create maximum of 16 number of threads. So, now I believe. I may need to create a thread pool specifying max size to 10.

**Can anyone please help me to understand and implement the thread pooling for blackberry for my current problem?**

**Also, I appreciate anyone giving me any other best approach which will fit for my requirement.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have everything what you need. So:

1. Create one `TaskWorker` for your application (use singelton)
2. Implement `Task` class from `TaskWorker` - `DownloadImageTask` (simply put everything from `Runnable.run()` to `Task.doTask()` method)
3. Instead of new thread creation in `Util.getWebData()` call `TaskWorker.addTask()`

There are probably more minor details but you could figure out how to finish it.

And I think it's better to have two method in `Callback` - `success(byte[] data)` and `error(Throwable error)` - to determine end result and escape converting images to `String` and back.