# IllegalThreadState exception while asynchronous list field implementation in Blackerry

Tags: java, multithreading, blackberry, try-catch, threadpool

This question is continuation to my previous question over stack overflow [how-to-download-images-asynchronously-from-web-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912647/how-to-download-images-asynchronously-from-web-server) . I am struggling to make the asynchronous list in blackberry. Now it is working fine for me. But it is giving me another problem now.

**What I have done so far**

1. Created a list view taking value from the XML feed
2. List is loaded with default thumbnail
3. Created `RunnableFactory`, limiting the thread pool size to 5 and then adding the runnable's to it. Runnable objects has the capability to download the image from server.
4. Now list loads perfectly fine asynchronously.

**Problem scenario**

On loading of the list screen it is initializing the `RunnableFactory` and then starting download and render images in list. But, let say I have 50 number of rows in the list. And now 10 images downloaded successfully, and RunnableFactory is still in action. At this point press back key and then click next. Practically it should come to the list screen and then again initiate the download process freshly. But it is throwing **IllegalThredState exception**

**My assumptions on this problem**

As all the threads are running, I might have to cancel all of the threads on back key pressed. If this is the problem can you please let me know how could i do it? As i have created multiple threads how could i manage to stop all threads and then navigate back ?

This looks like a more complex system. can anyone help me to understand what else could be the possible fix for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using any treadpool then you shutdown otherwise you can inturupt all treads on navigate to back.

Comment: what do you mean by shutdown? how to interrupt? I am crating threads as anonymous inner class. So how do  i interrupt all threads. I dont have reference of all of them.

Comment: @Nilanchala, what is `RunnableFactory`?  Is that a factory for creating `Runnables` that you wrote?  If you have that source, you may want to simply save any `Thread` objects you create as persistent member variables of your factory, so that you can later call `Thread.interrupt()` on them.

Answer (score 1):

I got this exception when I tried to start thread second time after finished run. Once started, a Thread may not be restarted.

Comment: .Please do share how to fix that.

Comment: Could you share code of your RunnableFactory or where do you start threads?